# text not centering on responsive background image

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I checked answers to relevant posts and they did not help. I want to have text centered on top of responsive background image - using CSS only if possible.

```css
/*beginning of styling for background img per smashing mag article*/

.hero {
    position: relative;
}
 .hero #page1img {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: 0/0 serif;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.hero #page1img .inner {
    padding-top: 64.700855%; /* 757px h divided by 1170w width/height of image */
    display: block;
    height: 0;
}

/*end of styling for background img per smashing mag article*/

h3 .intro-lead-in {
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 22px;
}

h1 .intro-heading {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Spinnaker', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
}

/* beginning of media queries for background image per smashing mag article*/

/* default screen, non-retina */
.hero #page1img { background-image: url("https://s9.postimg.org/6c1bhr9u7/header-970px-wide.jpg"); }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 538px) {
        /* Medium screen, non-retina */
        .hero #page1img { background-image: url("../img/header-538px-wide.jpg"); }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
        /* Small screen, non-retina */
        .hero #page1img { background-image: url("../img/header-290px-wide.jpg"); }
    }
      
/* end of media queries for background image per smashing mag article*/
```

```html
<div class= "row">
  <div class= "col-12">
   <div class="hero">
    <h3 class="intro-lead-in">Welcome to our Club!</h3>
    
    <h1 class="intro-heading">It's Nice to Meet You</h1>
    
    <span id="page1img" aria-label="MacGregor boats">
      <span class="inner"></span>
```

Approach was taken from Stephen Thomas's article in Smashing Magazine.
Demo for article implemented/working here: http://sathomas.me/continental/

This is my first question so apologies if I don't get it posted quite right.  Suggestions for improvement welcome!

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: HI Moses just added my code as Code Snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed you wanted the text to layer on top of the image, centered both horizontally and vertically.

Here's a quick approach without changing a lot of your code. 
The CSS that changed is in the `text` class (the class of the div I made). I'm basically just positioning it absolutely, then 40% from the top of the hero div. The color change was just to make the text more clear on your sample image.

I wrapped the text in a div to make it easy to position.

```css
/*beginning of styling for background img per smashing mag article*/

.hero {
  position: relative;
}

.hero #page1img {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font: 0/0 serif;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.hero #page1img .inner {
  padding-top: 64.700855%;
  /* 757px h divided by 1170w width/height of image */
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}


/*end of styling for background img per smashing mag article*/

h3 .intro-lead-in {
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 22px;
}

h1 .intro-heading {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Spinnaker', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  top:40%;
  color:#fff;
  
}


/* beginning of media queries for background image per smashing mag article*/


/* default screen, non-retina */

.hero #page1img {
  background-image: url("https://s9.postimg.org/6c1bhr9u7/header-970px-wide.jpg");
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 538px) {
  /* Medium screen, non-retina */
  .hero #page1img {
    background-image: url("../img/header-538px-wide.jpg");
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  /* Small screen, non-retina */
  .hero #page1img {
    background-image: url("../img/header-290px-wide.jpg");
  }
}


/* end of media queries for background image per smashing mag article*/
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="intro-lead-in">Welcome to our Club!</h3>
        <h1 class="intro-heading">It's Nice to Meet You</h1>
      </div>
      <span id="page1img" aria-label="MacGregor boats">
        <span class="inner">
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked exactly as you described.  No changes required.  Apparently I am not supposed to say thank you but many thanks!!!